# "cannot import name knowledge_engine" in PyKE

Tags: python, importerror, pyke

I am using PyKE package for building a Rule Engine in python using this tutorial 
http://pyke.keplerscience.org/install.html

After installing successfully, I wrote a sample python script, but am getting this error.

```
>> from pyke import knowledge_engine

ImportError: cannot import name knowledge_engine
```

I did not find any helping material in google. Can anybody help

Comment: Check that you've installed the correct version of pyke corresponding to your version of Python.

e.g. I used pyke3-1.1.1.zip because python3.6 is my default.

Comment: that link you provided goes to keplerscience. i was always wondering is it really PyKE - Python Knowledge Engine. i imply you may have installed wrong package - so you import doesn't work.

Comment: try this one: https://github.com/e-loue/pyke/issues/1